# Django Reportlab getKeepWithNext

Tags: django, reportlab

I am trying to add an image to a PDF generated in Reportlab. I am trying to access the image from a Django field, specifying the full path of the file.

When I run the below code I get: "Exception Value:  getKeepWithNext".

Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
def holding_pdf(self, course_slug, holding_slug):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        holding = HoldingDetail.objects.get(identifier=holding_slug)
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
                                rightMargin=72,
                                leftMargin=72,
                                topMargin=72,
                                bottomMargin=72,
                                pagesize=A4,
                                title=f"Why the {holding.name} is in the portfolio.pdf")
        elements = []
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        elements.append(Paragraph(str(holding.logo.path), styles['Normal']))
        elements.append(Image(holding.logo.path))
        print(holding.logo.path)
        doc.build(elements)
        buffer.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=False, filename=f"Why the {holding.name} is in the portfolio.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you post more info about the exception?

Comment: AttributeError at /leads/investsense-hub24/why/ETL0484AU/pdf/
getKeepWithNext
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/leads/investsense-hub24/why/ETL0484AU/pdf/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
getKeepWithNext
Exception Location: C:\Users\danie\Python\Django\PortfolioSense\env\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py, line 546, in __getattr__
Python Executable: C:\Users\danie\Python\Django\PortfolioSense\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're using an incorrect `Image` class. Verify the python imports in your file, and sure you use the `Image` *flowable* class provides by reportlab.

```py
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Image
```

Comment: That solved it, thank you so much! I realised I had imported 'from reportlab.platypus import Image' however had later imported 'from PIL import Image' which overrode the platypus import. I have now removed 'from PIL import Image' and it's working great. Thanks again!